# Why Visual Studio sometimes generates another (.XML) file identical to another (.AXML)?

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I work with Android Xamarin and sometimes my Visual Studio generates another (.XML) identical to the (.AXML) that I am working on. It happened to me a few times with few files. anyone knows the reason and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: Please update your Visual Studio. This question has been reported. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/780635/visual-studio-is-generating-xml-file-when-editing.html

Answer (score 1):

This is the known bug and it is expected to be fixed in visual studio 15.5